Find the pattern of the sequence under a function

Referring to the figure above, the red curve is $y=\sqrt{x}$. We enumerate the grid points under the curve, and then divide them into two groups (green ones $\{m_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and purple ones $\{n_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the figure above.) We have two sequences
$$\{m_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}=\{1,2,3,5,7,9,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,\dots\}$$
$$\{n_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}=\{4,6,8,10,12,15,18,21,24,\dots\}$$
How can I find the pattern (explicit formula) for the two sequences? More generally, I'd like to find the patterns of such sequences for other kinds of functions.
For the first row of green dots, we clearly have the patter
$$\lfloor\sqrt{1}\rfloor,\lfloor\sqrt{1}\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{2}\rfloor,\lfloor\sqrt{1}\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{3}\rfloor,\dots$$
We can find similar pattern for the second green row. However, it is not clear what the pattern is if we combine them.
If it is not possible to find the explicit formulae for $m_k$ and $n_k$, can we upper and lower bound them in a meaningful way?

Ultimately, the densities of these two sequences is $1/2,$ so I think a simple estimate is $m_k\sim 2k, n_k\sim 2k.$ But  I'm not sure how much better you can do. If there is a closed form, I bet it is very nasty.

If you search for the sequence "4,6,8,10,12,15,18,21,24" on OEIS, a few candidates do come up. But all of them begin with smaller values and thus don't seem applicable here.

Here is some Mathematica code for enumerating these points. First, we fix the value of $x$ and note that $y$ should not exceed $\sqrt{x}$. Since we want integer coordinates only, the points of interest are those of the form $(j,k)$ for positive integer $j$ and positive integer $k$ up to $k=\lfloor \sqrt{j}\rfloor$. However, the points are ordered from highest $k$ to lowest. Hence the points can be enumerated using nested Table commands in conjunction with a Reverse on the inner Table:
points=Flatten[Table[Reverse[Table[{j, k}, {k, 1, Floor[Sqrt[j]]}]], {j, 1, 12}],1]

where we enumerate points up to $j=12$ in agreement with the graph. This yields
{{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,2},{4,1},{5,2},{5,1},{6,2},{6,1},
 {7,2},{7,1},{8,2},{8,1},{9,3},{9,2},{9,1},{10,3},{10,2},{10,1},
 {11,3},{11,2},{11,1},{12,3},{12,2},{12,1}}

These are indeed the points shown with the correct order. The points in the first "row" are then those with $k=1$, and we can extract these indices via the Position command:
Flatten[Position[points, 1], {_, 1}]]

This yields {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25} which are the correct indices for the picture. If we want to get the purple points, then we instead want the position of points for which $k$ is odd. This can be done via
Flatten[Position[points, 1], {_, k_}/;OddQ[k]]]

to get {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25} in agreement with the image.
